# Upgrading an indexeddb which is shared by a PWA and its service worker

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, indexeddb

I have a PWA which uses indexeddb. (Actually the promise-aware "idb" layer on indexeddb).  The indexeddb component is for use offline, so that idb's OpenDB command can happen offline.  The js file that calls idb's OpenDB() is added to the service worker cache.  This is all fine.

Recently, I've been experimenting with using idb in the service worker itself. So I use importScripts() to load the js file which calls OpenDB().

From what I understand, files loaded by importScripts() are tret the same as the service worker itself in terms of caching.  This means that the loading of files within the importScripts() call bypass the service worker cache.  This is what I see.

This causes a problem when I upgrade the idb database.  When the new version of this file is loaded, inside the service worker, by importScripts() the database upgrade occurs.

However the old version of this file, which tries to open the old version of the database is still in the service worker cache.  That means my PWA (outside of the service worker) will try to open the older version of the database and fail, completely freezing the PWA.

How can I get around this?